# Modify React Component's State using jQuery/Plain Javascript from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am building a tiny Chrome Extension for my own personal use.

In Facebook's ads manager(Uses React) i want to change a textarea field's value to a value generated by my chrome extension.

i tried it doing the old fashion way like this

```
document.querySelector('textarea').value = myValue;
```

this changes the value on screen but in chrome's inspect element the value doesn't change and when i focus on the input element value resets.

Here is the picture of how react component looks like:

[image: 1]]

Here is the picture of this react components props & states:

[image: 2]]

In above component i want to change the state.displayValue to my value.

how it can be done?

Comment: I am dealing with a similar task now, have you found a solution?

Comment: have any solution?

Comment: hey @Santhos if it's still actual take a look at my answer

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned previously, you need to notify react about your manual changes. However, with React 16 this is [not so straightforward](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11488#issuecomment-347775628).

```
const element = document.querySelector('textarea')
const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true })
const previousValue = element.value

element.value = 'next value'
element._valueTracker.setValue(previousValue)
element.dispatchEvent(event)
```

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/93qnyon41r) with source code.
To see demo only you can open [this link](https://93qnyon41r.codesandbox.io/) and call `window.triggerChange('new value')` function directly from browser dev tools console.

You'll see React's `onChange` and then `setState` events being triggered!

Comment: I just tried this on the email field, document.querySelector('[type=email]') on this React page: http://seatgeek.com/cowboys/ and nothing happened

Comment: @AymonFournier hmm, I tried with this selector `document.querySelector('div.ghosted-input__field__main > input')` and script worked out as expected - email field value updated, submit form includes updated email. Selector is from Chrome Dev Tools, trimmed to few last entries

Comment: here is an example with full-length selector https://imgur.com/a/4MM3jc2 once input value is changed - further script should work for sure

Comment: For anyone working with select boxes try this: `element.value = 'somevalue'; element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

Comment: in my case I had to use `input` event for textareas and `blur` for inputs

Answer (score 2):

@Bandal react needs to be notified that the inputs value has changed. You will need to dispatch a change event after you have updated the value.

```
    document.querySelector('textarea').value = myValue;
    const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true })
    document.querySelector('textarea').dispatchEvent(event)
```

Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894637/how-to-programmatically-fill-input-elements-built-with-react)