Is it possible to use JS to set the value of a React + downshift autocomplete dropdown?
OBJECTIVE
I'm a support agent trying to create a Chrome Extension to automate the filling out of Zendesk forms to make my job easier. I'm using the console at the moment.
SITUATION
Unfortunately, Zendesk uses React + downshift, which is complicating things as I am a newb at React and never used downshift. When I try to do it using normal means like changing the .value property and then dispatching events, the value change never registers.
WHAT I'VE TRIED
First of all, I simulate a click on the outer container, which opens the dropdown as expected.

Different combinations of dispatched events like first input, then change
Typing in the text by using keydown events to input the letters one by one
Using the blur event
Simulating a click on the actual input itself after the first simulated click on the parent
Both focusing on the input itself and not

FORM ELEMENT HTML
<div id="ember3412" class="ember-view">
    <!---->
    <div data-garden-id="forms.field" data-garden-version="8.74.3" data-test-id="ticket-form-field-dropdown-field-29533817" aria-describedby="7val-tooltip_1.0.6" data-garden-container-id="containers.tooltip" data-garden-container-version="1.0.6" class="sc-anv20o-3 gAALKx StyledField-sc-12gzfsu-0 glOpOr">
        <label data-garden-id="forms.input_label" data-garden-version="8.74.3" data-garden-container-id="containers.tooltip" data-garden-container-version="1.0.6" id="downshift-5-label" for="downshift-5-input" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="8val-tooltip_1.0.6"
        class="sc-anv20o-4 iIWDoF StyledLabel-sc-2utmsz-0 bYrRLL">HO Assignee*</label>
        <div data-garden-id="dropdowns.faux_input" data-garden-version="8.54.3" aria-invalid="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" data-toggle="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="downshift-5-label" data-test-id="ticket-form-field-dropdown-button"
        class="StyledTextInput-sc-k12n8x-0 sc-anv20o-0 kptXaI StyledFauxInput-sc-1l592ed-0 iJWzSI StyledTextFauxInput-sc-yqw7j9-0 gdXore">
            <div data-garden-id="dropdowns.select" data-garden-version="8.54.3" class="StyledSelect-sc-xifmwj-0 eSliJF"><span class="sc-anv20o-1 hGMRMW"><div data-garden-id="typography.ellipsis" data-garden-version="8.74.0" title="-" class="StyledEllipsis-sc-1u4uqmy-0 gxcmGf">-</div></span></div>
            <input data-garden-id="dropdowns.input" data-garden-version="8.54.3"
            aria-invalid="false" data-garden-container-id="containers.field.input" data-garden-container-version="3.0.15" id="downshift-5-input" aria-labelledby="downshift-5-label" aria-autocomplete="list" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" class="StyledInput-sc-hzhvmp-0 etSNgg StyledTextInput-sc-k12n8x-0 jEqqcP"
            value="">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 16 16" aria-hidden="true" data-garden-id="forms.media_figure" data-garden-version="8.74.3" class="StyledTextMediaFigure-sc-1qepknj-0 lnDzQq">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="M12.688 5.61a.5.5 0 01.69.718l-.066.062-5 4a.5.5 0 01-.542.054l-.082-.054-5-4a.5.5 0 01.55-.83l.074.05L8 9.359l4.688-3.75z"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

REACT DEV TOOLS HIERARCHY
The actual input element itself is the one indicated by the arrow:

CODE
I've tried many, many things but this is the first thing I tried:
function insertText(parent, text, selectorDescription) {
    if (!parent) {
        console.error(`Parent not found for ${selectorDescription}`);
        return;
    }

    let element = parent.querySelector('input');

    if (!element) {
        console.error(`Input field not found for ${selectorDescription}`);
        return;
    }

    element.click(); // tried with and without
    element.focus(); // tried with and without
    
    element.value = text;

    element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true  }));
    element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true  }));
}

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct approach in this context?

Found the answer in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894637/how-to-programmatically-fill-input-elements-built-with-react#:~:text=reproduced%20here%20for%20convenience%3A
